# What is the difference between a MacBook Pro MPXW2D/A-056332 and MPXV2D/A-056248

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I have been doing some research in preparation for buying a new laptop, and I am having trouble figuring out the differences between different offerings. For example, one vendor offers both a model which the vendor calls "MPXW2D/A-056332" as well as one called "MPXV2D/A-056248". Both have the same price and the same specs, but the vendor only lists some general specs such as size of RAM and SSD, clock frequency of CPU, etc. The more subtle differences are missing.

What are the differences between the two? And how can I figure that out myself? [*Identify your MacBook Pro*](https://support.apple.com/HT201300#models) only confirms that those are, in fact, latest model 13″ MacBook Pros, but doesn't explain the differences between them. Following the link leads to the [*Apple Tech Specs* page](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP755) for that model, but that doesn't explain the differences either.

EveryMac's Lookup page identifies both as a [*Apple MacBook Pro "Core i5" 3.1 13" Touch/Mid-2017*](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-3.1-13-mid-2017-retina-display-touch-bar-specs.html), but also doesn't explain what the differences between the two models are. Same with [Wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Technical_specifications_4).

It gets even worse trying to compare offers from different vendors which only list different subsets of the specs each.

How can I find out what the differences between those two (and other) models are, or at least determine whether the differences are significant or irrelevant?

Comment: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=https://communities.apple.com/de/thread/200028965&prev=search this says that it's about SSD difference. That's the only thing that comes with "site:apple.com" on google.